# array, horizontal space/ margin

Tags: equations, align, vertical-alignment

How can I make the horizontal space between the vertical line and the percent symbol disappear?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=13pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english, main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{aligned-overset}



\begin{document}
\begin[equation}
\begin{array}{|l@{}}
         \text{\%} \; x^{2(k+1)}=(\beta_{1} \beta_{2})^{k+1} x^{0}, \\
         \text{\%} \; \Delta_{2(k+1)}= (\beta_{1} \beta_{2})^{k+1} \Delta_{0} 
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{array}{|@{}l@{}}` should remove the white space between teh vertical line and the percent sign.

Comment: Apart from that, please be aware, that you can only use the `array` environment in math mode. Your MWE currently results in an error message informing you about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is `\begin{array}{|@{}l@{}}`.  The initial `@{}`, missing from the OP's code, overrides the default padding before the column.  If you want something between the default value and no space, you could, for example, use `\begin{array}{|@{\hspace{1pt}}l@{}}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=13pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english, main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{aligned-overset}



\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{|@{}l@{}}
         \text{\%} \; x^{2(k+1)}=(\beta_{1} \beta_{2})^{k+1} x^{0}, \\
         \text{\%} \; \Delta_{2(k+1)}= (\beta_{1} \beta_{2})^{k+1} \Delta_{0} 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]